# Data fetched from server not showing at frontend screen (MERN Stack)

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, react-redux, mern

I am trying to develop an Amazon-like website by following some lectures on youtube. I created a MongoDB database and then through the express server fetched the data and then passed it to the frontend react application. I checked on the console, and found the product data fetched is correct and the redux store is also showing product data but somehow it is not getting displayed.
Please help.

Please see the code of ProductScreen. I tried to check by putting  console.log ({product.name} )  in the return statement. And this is coming blank so I guess problem is product is not getting assigned to const product in the code.

```html
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { detailsProduct } from '../actions/productActions';
import LoadingBox from '../components/LoadingBox';
import MessageBox from '../components/MessageBox';
import Rating from '../components/Rating';

export default function ProductScreen(props) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const productId = props.match.params.id;
  const [qty, setQty] = useState(1);
  const productDetails = useSelector((state) => state.productDetails);
  const { loading, error, product } = productDetails;

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(detailsProduct(productId));
  }, [dispatch, productId]);
  const addToCartHandler = () => {
    props.history.push(`/cart/${productId}?qty=${qty}`);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      {loading ? (
        <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>
      ) : error ? (
        <MessageBox variant="danger">{error}</MessageBox>
      ) : (
        <div>
          <Link to="/">Back to result</Link>
          <div className="row top">
            <div className="col-2">
              <img
                className="large"
                src={product.image}
                alt={product.name}
              ></img>
            </div>
            <div className="col-1">
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <h1>{product.name}</h1>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <Rating
                    rating={product.rating}
                    numReviews={product.numReviews}
                  ></Rating>
                </li>
                <li>Pirce : ${product.price}</li>
                <li>
                  Description:
                  <p>{product.description}</p>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div className="col-1">
              <div className="card card-body">
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <div className="row">
                      <div>Price</div>
                      <div className="price">${product.price}</div>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <div className="row">
                      <div>Status</div>
                      <div>
                        {product.countInStock > 0 ? (
                          <span className="success">In Stock</span>
                        ) : (
                          <span className="danger">Unavailable</span>
                        )}
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                  {product.countInStock > 0 && (
                    <>
                      <li>
                        <div className="row">
                          <div>Qty</div>
                          <div>
                            <select
                              value={qty}
                              onChange={(e) => setQty(e.target.value)}
                            >
                              {[...Array(product.countInStock).keys()].map(
                                (x) => (
                                  <option key={x + 1} value={x + 1}>
                                    {x + 1}
                                  </option>
                                )
                              )}
                            </select>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <button
                          onClick={addToCartHandler}
                          className="primary block"
                        >
                          Add to Cart
                        </button>
                      </li>
                    </>
                  )}
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Adding redux store code:

```html
import { createStore, compose, applyMiddleware, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { cartReducer } from './reducers/cartReducers';
import {
  productDetailsReducer,
  productListReducer,
} from './reducers/productReducers';

const initialState = {
  cart: {
    cartItems: localStorage.getItem('cartItems')
      ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cartItems'))
      : [],
  },
};
const reducer = combineReducers({
  productList: productListReducer,
  productDetails: productDetailsReducer,
  cart: cartReducer,
});
const composeEnhancer = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  composeEnhancer(applyMiddleware(thunk))
);
```

Please see the screenshots.

[image]

Comment: Can you add your reduce store?

Comment: @Filipe, I added code for redux store

Answer (score 0):

There was one minor mistake, in the productRouter code at the backend (See code below). Instead of res.send (product)...I was sending res. send ({product}) and because of that the json object I was getting was in this format: productDetails { product: {product :{....}}}. So, when I was referring product.object, it is basically null and so I was not getting any rendering. So, either I had to use product.product.object or simply correct code on productRouter.

Code:

```
productRouter.get(
  '/:id',
  expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const product = await Product.findById(req.params.id);
    if (product) {
      **res.send(product);**
    } else {
      res.status(404).send({ message: 'Product Not Found' });
    }
  })
);
```